# Android Dev Tutorial: What is `Infinity` in ViewPager Sample?

Tags: android

What is the below code in the Android Developper's Official Tutorial, [Using ViewPager for Screen Slides](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/training/animation/screen-slide.html)?

```
public class ZoomOutPageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {
    //...

    public void transformPage(View view, float position) {
        //...

        if (position < -1) { // **[-Infinity,-1)
            //...
        } else if (position <= 1) { // [-1,1]
            //...
        } else { // (1,+Infinity]
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meaning of these comments is more or less:

```
if (position < -1) { // here go all 'position' values lesser than -1
    //...
} else if (position <= 1) { // 'position' in range from -1 to 1, including both -1 and 1
    //...
} else { // and then all 'position' values greater than 1 go here
    //...
}
```

If you are looking for an "infinity" value for `Float` type in Android then there are `Float.NEGATIVE_INFINITY` and `Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY` values representing them.

Answer (score 1):

In the example on the site, the comment below actually explains the behaviour

```
if (position < -1) { // [-Infinity,-1)
    // This page is way off-screen to the left.
    view.setAlpha(0);
}
```

What the negative infinity to -1 describes is the `position` parameters limits for the `if` block to pass (i.e. be true). In the case `-Infinity < position < -1` this code will execute, which means the code below wille execute at the following points:

```
else if (position <= 1) { // [-1,1]
        //true for when position is less than or equal to 1
        //but only run when code is greater than or equal to -1
        //as this is an else-if
    } else { // [1,+Infinity]
        //true for when position is greater than 1
    }
```

The `position` variable accounts for the positioning of the fragment that is to be transformed.

So from this you can see that the limit of negative infinity and -1 means that the actual view is off screen in the **left direction**. It is off screen in the **right direction** when position is greater than one and on screen when neither of these conditions are satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

Infinity means that the actual `view` is way off screen left (negative infinity) or right (positive infinity), so you don't need to apply a scale factor, just set the alpha value to 0

You have to understand that this is a code used to describe the `view` transition when swiping through the `ViewPager` fragments, so, when the `view` is still on screen, you apply the `scaleFactor` and when it's off, just set it to invisible, or alpha 0.